# How to add Markdown to a Confluence page via REST API?

Tags: markdown, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I'm working on a method to programmatically post Markdown to a Confluence page via the REST API. With [the REST API documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/confluence-rest-api-examples/#create-a-new-page), I've figured out how to create/update pages. The problem is, the only way I know how to add Markdown/Confluence wiki to a page is by manually hitting the "Insert Content" button and selecting "Markdown". So how would I do this via the REST API?

I found [this question](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/Import-markdown-into-Confluence/qaq-p/211797) from 6 years ago that doesn't help, and both [Jira](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONFSERVER-55637) [issues](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONFSERVER-59543) have been open without update for almost as long.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see a markdown macro in my confluence, so not sure if you're using a macro or how you add markdown to confluence. But usually if it's a macro, it's very simple. You will need a [Confluence Source Editor](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1210722/confluence-source-editor?tab=overview&hosting=server). There are more if this one doesn't work. 

Then you can create a test page, add the macro you want, then you get the code for that macro. The code is simply XHTML confluence format.

Idk about Rest API, but with Conf Python API, you can just do confluence.update_page()...

Comment: to update a page's xhtml source code. Can use BS4 or something else to add the Macro code somewhere in your page source code, then update it with update_page()